# Puppeteer: Uncaught TimeoutError TimeoutError: Timeout exceeded while waiting for event

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

[image]

I'm trying to get the response headers and cookies for

```
url= 'https://www.asr.pima.gov/Parcel/GetParcel'
```

I have the following code using node and puppeteer:

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
    executablePath: executablePath(),

});
let req;
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto(url);
const finalResponse = await page.waitForResponse(response =>
    response.url() === 'https://www.asr.pima.gov/Parcel/GetParcel' && response.status() === 200
);
```

.......

As I step through the code there is a delay at the final line ( starting at: const finalResponse = ..), The error is in the title.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't see a [mcve] here. Is the URL correct and actually showing up in the network tab? What's `url` set to? Usually, if you're waiting for a request that's triggered by the page loading, you want to set the promise before you `goto`, especially if you're waiting for the `'load'` event by default here. By the time you start waiting for the response, it's already arrived.

Comment: @ggorlen, - I've added the url above. When I  paste the url into the browser with devtools open , I can see the request in the network tab ( Please see screenshot above ). I'm  the one triggering this request by pasting it in to chrome.

Comment: Thanks, yeah--you're navigating to the URL before you start waiting for the request. Start the request, do the nav, then await the request promise. Better yet, simply assign the response to `await page.goto()`, as in `const finalResponse = await page.goto(url)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be overthinking it. `page.goto` returns the response you seem to be looking for:

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer"); // ^19.1.0

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  const url = "https://www.asr.pima.gov/Parcel/GetParcel";
  const finalResponse = await page.goto(url);
  console.log(finalResponse.headers());
  console.log(await page.cookies());
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());
```

Now, let's say you're looking for some other response that's kicked off by the initial page load. A way to do it is by planting the promise without `await` before `goto`, then beginning navigation.

```js
let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  const url = "https://www.asr.pima.gov/Parcel/GetParcel";
  const finalResponseP = page.waitForResponse(res => res.url() === url);
  await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: "domcontentloaded"});
  const finalResponse = await finalResponseP;
  console.log(finalResponse.headers());
  console.log(await page.cookies());
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());
```

This works for the base `url` as shown above, but not necessarily, so it's a more general solution than the first code block. If you have multiple responses, you can try `Promise.all` or add a listener with `page.on("response", res => {})`.

---

Based on the follow-up, it sounds like you were expecting cookies to be set on this request, but I don't see any on a visit to the page in my browser.

If you're looking for the cookie that's returned after you enter a search, you can access it as follows:

```js
let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  const ua =
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36";
  await page.setUserAgent(ua);
  const url = "https://www.asr.pima.gov/Parcel/GetParcel";
  const finalResponse = await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: "domcontentloaded"});
  console.log(finalResponse.headers());
  await page.type("#parcel", "123-45-678A");
  await Promise.all([
    page.waitForResponse(res => res.url().includes("GetSearchResults")),
    page.click('[type="submit"]'),
  ]);
  console.log(await page.cookies());
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());
```

Comment: Thank you, I am now getting headers but no cookies -using your code please see edit above.

Comment: I'm removing your edit--the original question wasn't really about the cookies, it was about getting the response. Please ask a new question if you have a new question. Thanks. That said, when I visit the page, I'm not assigned any cookies, so it seems accurate as far as I can tell. Which cookies were you expecting?

Comment: Entering a search results in a cookie being set. If that's what you want, I've added code to get that cookie.